# Solving org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure - Cassandra Datastax Java Driver, Maven, Glassfish 4

Tags: maven, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, glassfish-4, datastax-java-driver

I'm just posting this as a solution for those who encounters error in using Datastax's Java Driver on Glassfish 4 through Maven deployment.

As was written on Datastax's web site, the dependency of the driver is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately, if you deploy this to Glassfish 4 through Maven, it will throw  org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure...just like the below:

```
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Set<Service>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)]
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Set<Service>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject com.google.common.util.concurrent.ServiceManager(Set<Service>)]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:403)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:325)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:177)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:208)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:519)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:505)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:480)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:536)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:216)
... 36 more
]]
```

So, to solve this, just change the  xml portion to this when deploying to Glassfish 4:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Normally when sharing your own knowledge you would post a question and separate answer, then accept your own answer. Putting everything in the question doesn't make much sense.